Native relation field in custom element type
I created a custom element type and configured it to have a field layout manager. Using the FieldLayout::EVENT_DEFINE_NATIVE_FIELDS event I attached a default TitleField to the layout that is not deletable.
What I want to do now is add another default field to the field layout but the field type should be Users (Relation field). How can I do this? (Unfortunately there is no native relation field in craft/fieldlayoutelements)


I could probably create my own native field by extending the BaseNativeField class but I'm afraid that I would have to re-implement the relation field according to the BaseRelationField class which has 1.500 LoC. Is there another way?
